# How to implement an XNA-Game into a Windows-Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xna, xna-4.0

I want to add a updatable and drawable Control into a windows Form, wherein I can let my game being played, but also is possible to go go fullscreen, if needed. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there another reason other then to switch between windowed and fullscreen? If not, then the easiest way go about this is to use the FullScreen property of the GraphicsDevice.

Comment: @borrillis It´s only for the game to start in windowed mode but also can go in fullscreen mode like in Minecraft or in 3D Pinball (included in Windows XP)

Comment: I want to use this control for the game editor, where I can create Maps and Objects etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial, it's quite easy.
You only have to make the base itself, such as the update void.
[Here!](http://forum.chaos-project.com/index.php?topic=8068.0)